# Azure Node.js query other table while inserting object and send push notification

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, azure, push-notification

I want to send a push notification to a specific user, while inserting into a table on Azure, using a node.js API. The problem is, that the object which supposed to be inserted doesn't contain the id of the user, who should receive the notification, therefore I have to get it from another table, querying it based on one property of the object to be inserted. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work, any idea?

```
var azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps'),
   promises = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/utilities/promises'),
   logger = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/logger');
   var table = azureMobileApps.table();
   table.insert(function (context) {      
   logger.info('Running Table.insert');
   return context.execute()
       .then(function (results) {
           var queries = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/query');
           var query = queries.create('Table2').where({id: context.item.someProperty});
           var table2 = context.tables('Table2');

           table2.read(query).then(function (result) {
               var tag = result.userId;
               var payload = '{"messageParam": "your notification"}';

               if (context.push) {
                    context.push.send(tag, payload, function (error) {
                          if (error) {
                               logger.error('Error while sending push notification: ', error);
                           } else {
                              logger.info('Push notification sent successfully!');
                         }
                    });
                }
                return results;
           });
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
           logger.error('Error while running context.execute: ', error);
       });
});
module.exports = table;
```

**UPDATE**
I did't get any error messages. The code was run from the azure portal, it can be found in table.js file. I tried to test the code using the XCode's simulator by inserting an object into the table with an iOS app I was developping and I was waiting for the push notification in an iPhone, logged in to the app with the user who was supposed to get the notification. 
When I tried to insert the item to the table, the webservice didn't end, neighter the completion nor the fail block was invoked. I checked, the code works fine without the query part: `table.read(query).then(function (result) {`
so my guess is that the problem could be with the table querying, but unfortunatelly I am not familiar with node.js and I couldn't find any usefull documentation regarding this, nor can I debug my code.

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT You can find the answer in the update.